# Python socket chat issue

Tags: python, sockets

I have client and server sample codes. I can send message from client to server and I cant receive message from server to client. what is the issue ?

Server.py file

```
#server
import socket;
import time;

HOST = "localhost";
PORT = 5454;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
s.bind((HOST,PORT));
while True:

  print "Client says: " + s.recv(1024);

  data = raw_input("Enter..... ")  ;
  s.sendto(data,(HOST, PORT));

  if data=="bye" or s.recv(1024)=="bye":
       print "Exiting..................";
       time.sleep(1);
       break;
```

Client.py file

```
#client
import socket;
import time;

HOST = "localhost";
PORT = 5454;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
s.connect((HOST,PORT));
while True:

  data = raw_input("Enter..... ")
  s.sendto(data,(HOST,PORT)) ;

  print "Server says: " + s.recv(1024);

  if data=="bye" or s.recv(1024)=="bye":
       print "Exiting...........";
       time.sleep(1);
       break;
```

What is the issue of above code....

First time i can send mesage from client to server. can not send message server to clint. have to wait more time.... but no responce. help me

Comment: @dsgdfg This is a data gram protocol, no accept needed.

Comment: thanks i will remove it

Answer (score 1):

You expect to receive twice as much data as you send.

```
  print "Server says: " + s.recv(1024);

  if data=="bye" or s.recv(1024)=="bye":
```

Calling receive each time will wait for data on the socket. Store the message received first, then manipulate that message.

```
  msg = s.recv(1024)
  print "Server says: " + msg
  if data=="bye" or msg=="bye":
```

Comment: msg = s.recv(1024);
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host